# JSON file creation through a form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I am looking for a way in which to create/write to an external, custom JSON file.

I have a form with multiple elements in (input/textarea/select) and what I want is when I click the submit/save button, for the information in this form to be converted into JSON information and saved to the external file so it can be retrieved whenever called. So it stays there forever.

its for a preset selector. Fill out the form style options, click save preset and then later call it to fill the form back in (This I have a solution to - jQuery form autofill)

Cheers for your help.

Comment: By "file" do you just meant storage on the client? Sounds like `localStorage` with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` should work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data to another php file using

```
    $('#saveBtn').click(function() {
    var htmltesxtbox1 = $('#textbox1').val();
    var htmltesxtbox2 = $('#textbox2').val();
    var htmltesxtbox3 = $('#tesxtbox3').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: yourphpfileUrl,
        data: {textbox1: htmltesxtbox1, textbox2: htmltesxtbox2, tesxtbox3: htmltesxtbox3}
    }).done(function(data) {
        //do some thing after pass the data

    });

});
```

then in the php file you can get data and do what ever the thing you need to do.

Comment: For getting all fields from the form you could use jQuery's ```$('form').serialze()``` More info in [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        //export to file
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Demo for Json Convert](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/sxGtM/5212/)

> Export To File

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {

            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "MyReport_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

[Demo to Export File](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/JXrwM/851/)

[Combine Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/sxGtM/5217/)